# Getting all documents in Elasticsearch where a field value matches any of array element

Tags: elasticsearch

What I would like to do is to retrieve all documents where a field value matches any of the values in an array.

So from an array of ids: `[id1, id2, id3, ..., idn]`, find all documents which has any of these ids.

I can currently achieve that by repeating a `match` inside of a `should`, but it does not seem like the right approach.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "activityOwnerId": "id1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "activityOwnerId": "id2"
          }
        },
        ... and so on
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**How can I get all documents which matches one of the elements in an array?**

**EDIT**

Using `terms` query as suggested by @Val does not return any results in Kibana:

No results when querying with `Terms`:
[image: No results with Terms]

Results found (with the same id), when using `should`:
[image: Results with Should and listing each id]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking at exact matches, you can leverage the [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) instead, which takes an array as input:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "activityOwnerId.keyword": [id1, id2, id3, ..., idn]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get no results back in Kibana when trying to use the `terms` query. I have updated my answer with 2 screenshots, where the first one is attempting to use `terms` as you suggested. Can you see what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: You might need to run the query on the `activityOwnerId.keyword` field instead, since you're doing an exact match. Can you try that?

Comment: Ahh, that's it! ElasticSearch is funny thing sometimes. Thank you Val!

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned it, I (wrongly) assumed that `activityOwnerId` was already of keyword type (which it should be)

Comment: Okay, I see. So currently it's a `text` type in my mapping.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of queries in elasicsearch

1. Term Queries - which searches the exact terms mentioned in the value
2. Full-Text queries - Which first analyses the query values, by the analyser mentioned in the field in the mapping

If you want to go form term query, then Answer mentioned  by @Val, is perfect,

if you want to write a full-text query, you can use this

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "activityOwnerId:(id1 OR id2 OR id3...)"
    }
  }
}
```